# Is there a way to add superscript and subscript to the same element using ggtext,<sub>&<sup>?

Tags: r

I have a necessary reason to use 'ggtext'

This is not the result I want,You can see that there is a big gap between '2-' and 'O'

```
library(ggtext)
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  label = c(
    'SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>'
  ),
  x = c(.5),
  y = c(.5),
)
ggplot(df) +
  aes(
    x, y, label = label
  ) +
  geom_richtext() +
  xlim(0, 1)+ 
  ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]

This is the result I want, but this is not achieved with ggtext's html tags sub and sup

[image]

Comment: I haven't found anything that suggests HTML or markdown (supported by `geom_richtext`) can support an "atop" like structure. I know you said you are using `ggtext` for a reason; if that reason is not present in _this_ geom, can you do a mix of `geom_richtext` and a normal `geom_text` using expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any reference that suggests HTML or markdown support the "atop" notion (aka vertical alignment of superscript and subscript); some answers have even said "not possible", though I can't say with certainty that that's the case.

This is possible using the basic `geom_label` and plotmath-expressions.

Since you said that you have reason to use `ggtext`, is it possible to separate the labels with this feature?

```r
df <- tibble(
  label = c(
    'SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>',
    "'SO'[4]^'2-'"
  ),
  x = c(.5, .5),
  y = c(.4, .6),
  parse = c(FALSE, TRUE)
)
ggplot(df) +
  aes( x, y, label = label ) +
  geom_richtext(data = ~ filter(., !parse)) +
  geom_label(data = ~ filter(., parse), parse=TRUE) +
  xlim(0, 1) + ylim(0, 1)
```

[image: ggplot with two labels, the first has the superscript and subscript properly aligned vertically, the second is the original and has the subscript first and the superscript slightly to the right]

If desired, you can add some space after the `SO` to make it a little less cramped; for instance, `"'SO '[4]^'2-'"` results in

[image: same plot as above, with a little more horizontal space between the "SO" and the superscript/subscript]

Comment: The html needed would be the MathML which has the `<msupsub>` tag, but `geom_richtext()` doesn't support it.

Comment: I don't know that I understand. Your question has HTML, but you're saying your real data is using MathML that `geom_richtext` does not support?

Comment: I suggest that if you're looking at all chemical formulae like that, it might not be too hard to convert it from MathML to plotmath-expressions ... not ideal, but maybe your shortest path?